# Proof using squeeze theorem for convergence of infinite sequence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose we have a fixed, bounded infinite sequence$\ (b_{n}) \ $and for each$\ n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}, \ $we set$\ w_{n} \ =inf\{b_{n},b_{n+1},b_{n+2},...\} \ $and$\ g_{n} \ =sup\{b_{n},b_{n+1},b_{n+2},...\}. \ $We also let$\ g=inf\{g_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\} \ $and$\ w=sup\{w_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\}. \ $Prove if $\ w = g, \ $then$\ (b_{n}) \ \rightarrow w=g. $

**My *attempt* at proving this:**

We know that if $\ a_{n}\le\ k_{n}\le\ c_{n}\ \ $for all $\ n \ $sufficiently large and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n} \ =\lim_{n\to \infty}c_{n}=a $$

Then, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}k_{n}\ =a $$

It is stated above that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}w_{n}\ =\lim_{n\to \infty}g_{n} $$

Therefore, if we can show the following is true (for all for all $\ n \ $sufficiently large):

$$\ g_{n}\le\ b_{n}\le\ w_{n}\ \ $$

Then we have successfully shown that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}b_{n}=w=g\ $$

We know that $\ g_{n} \ $is *monotone decreasing* (non-increasing) and that $\ w_{n} \ $is *monotone increasing* (non-decreasing), and therefore, for $\ n \ $sufficiently large, we can assume $\ g_{n}\le\ b_{n}\le\ w_{n}\ \ $ and thus, we can conclude that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}b_{n}=w=g\ $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up some notations. You have by the definitions

$$w_n \le b_n \le g_n$$

for all $n$. You wrote it down the other way around. Then, as you correctly said,$ g_n$ is non-increasing, so having an infimum means it has the limit, same goes to $w_n$, which concludes your proof, since those limits are assumed to be the same.